# Not able to open a page directly angular

Tags: angular, routes

On localhost, everything works fine but when I deployed my files on Heroku pages are not able to open directly through URL

> Cannot GET /profile

internally pages when redirection is done through `this.router.navigate(['/profile']);` this works fine i get to url page but when i directly open ,error
**server.js file**

```
const express = require('express');
 const app = express();
 app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
 app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

also same error with images too cannot load them, do i have to again define routes here as i have defined in **app.module.ts** like

```
 RouterModule.forRoot([
 { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
 { path: 'admin', component: AdminComponent,canActivate:[AdminAuthGaurd]},
 { path: 'profile', component: ProfileComponent},
 { path: 'accessdenied', component: NoAccessComponent},
 { path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent }
])
```

how can I

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
this.router.navigate(['*']);
  });
```

because I have already handled these request on my angular app!
any help will be great thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure express to always serve up index.html, whatever the url, this should allow you to reach your routes from external links:

```
//  all routes lead to to index.html
let router = express.Router();
router.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(DIR, 'index.html'));
});
this.express.use('*', router);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's normal. In Angular, you have only one file to be served - `index.html` - which is served when you GET `www.yourdomain.com`. Because of this, we call Angular apps as SPA (single page application) - we really have one page to be served and the Angular app routes should be done inside the app by itself.

When you try open `/profile`, you are leaving the Angular app and reaching Express app scope, which doesn't have any route to handle such request. If you had something like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
   // do something
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

you'd get something, but it'd closes the Angular app (`index.html`).

You can read more about here in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration).

Read about [hashing strategy](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/routing-strategies/#_hashlocationstrategy) and tell me if it helps you. With hashing, you can GET

```
www.yourdomain.com/#/profile
```

and the page never gets sent to the server anything past the # in a URL. If you use such strategy, you should keep the original Express server code.

Comment: Updated my question please check

Comment: Updated my answer.